# Excepción System.AccessViolationException en VS Community 2015

Tags: vb.net

Desde hace una semana estoy padeciendo un error en una aplicación de mediana entidad desarrollada para mi empresa.

La aplicación, desarrollada en VB.NET, consta de una interfaz muy básica (Windows Form Application) que procesa abundante información de estructuras metálicas que han sido modeladas en una aplicación externa de diseño estructural llamada *Staad.Pro* (muy común en el sector del Petróleo y Gas).

Obtiene información externa de dos fuentes:

- Un archivo de Staad.Pro, a través de la librería *openstaad.dll*
  distribuida con Staad.Pro.
- Diversos archivos de Excel, a través de los objetos `Connection` y
  `Recordset` de *ADO*.

La aplicación acumula tres años de uso satisfactorio. Recientemente introduje el proceso en segundo plano de los datos (una de las varias cuestiones que estaban pendientes desde el primer momento de su desarrollo) y la definición de una serie de datos de configuración de cada proyecto en un archivo externo de Excel, datos que anteriormente se definían de forma directa en el código.

Este archivo de configuración se lee directamente en Excel abriendo una instancia de la aplicación (Excel), a diferencia del resto, que como ya dije se leen mediante objetos ADO. A su vez, la ruta de este archivo de configuración está definida en un archivo de texto único al que se remite siempre la aplicación para leer dicha ruta, cuyo contenido (la ruta) puede modificarse a través de la propia aplicación mediante un objeto `OpenFileDialog`.

Especifico en particular estas cuestiones porque se trata de los cambios que introduje con anterioridad a la aparición del error. Han mediado también dos semanas de inactividad por vacaciones en las que han existido actualizaciones de Windows (algunas supongo que vinculadas con el *ransomware* de reciente actualidad).

Pues bien, el error que ha surgido desde hace una semana es el siguiente:

> ```
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>  occurred in mscorlib.dll 
>  Additional information: Intento de leer o escribir en la memoria
>  protegida. A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada.
> ```

Se produce al abrir una conexión de ADO con el siguiente código:

```
    cnn1.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;" &
              "Data Source=" & rutaarchivo & ";" &
              "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";")
```

Se trata de la segunda conexión de ADO que abre el programa. La primera conexión se cierra y el objeto correspondiente se vacía. Tratando de identificar el error, recurrí a la lectura directa del archivo abriendo Excel, evitando el recurso a ADO. El problema se reproduce nuevamente en otra conexión posterior con ADO, que vuelve a ser la segunda que realiza el programa.

El error no se produce siempre, de tal manera que recién abierto el proyecto en VS Community 2015 y al ejecutar el programa por primera vez no suele aparecer el error, pero sí tras una segunda ejecución.

Otras veces, con menor frecuencia, el error se localiza en la llamada a la subrutina que establece la conexión con el archivo de Excel (no a nivel del código de la propia subrutina), con un mensaje distinto:

> El Asistente para la depuración administrada
>   'FatalExecutionEngineError' ha detectado un problema en (rutaarchivo)
>
> Información adicional: El runtime detectó un error irrecuperable. La
>   dirección del error fue 0xf923127e, en el subproceso 0x2abc. El código
>   de error es `0xc0000005`. Es posible que este error sea un error de
>   CLR o de partes no seguras y no verificables de código de usuario.
>   Entre los orígenes más habituales de este error se encuentran los
>   errores de cálculo de referencias para la interoperabilidad COM o
>   PInvoke, que pueden dañar la pila.

En la búsqueda de un patrón para el error también he detectado un fallo en el segundo uso de un mismo tipo de objeto de la librería *openstaad.dll*, con el siguiente mensaje:

> ```
> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
> occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code
> Additional information: La memoria está bloqueada. (Excepción de
> HRESULT: 0x8002000D (DISP_E_ARRAYISLOCKED))
> ```

La búsqueda en internet de información sobre este error (System.AccessViolationException) me ha conducido a los dos siguientes enlaces fundamentalmente, de los que no he sacado nada en claro, aparte de vagas intuiciones (he probado a reinstalar *Access Database Engine*, a definir la variable de entorno que se especifica y a modificar la versión de *.NET Framework* de la aplicación):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294543/programs-randomly-getting-system-accessviolationexception

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/106826/OpenFileDialog-OleDbConnection-AccessViolationExce

Comment: Hola Alberto, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te he eliminado ciertas frases que son del todo innecesarias y subjetivas. Trata de mantener las preguntas y respuestas objetivas. Para más informacion has de leer el [tour](para ver como funciona el sitio) y [ask] para mejorar la calidad de las preguntas. Un saludo